# Haskell beginner: Is this too imperative like?

Tags: haskell

*Sorry for the extremely elementary question, but I am just starting out with Haskell.

I have a Snap web app with a handler `handleUsernameCheck`. I am trying to get the `username` as parameter and use it to query Postgresql.

The code I came up looks something like this:

```
handleUsernameCheck :: Handler App App ()
handleUsernameCheck = do
    username <- getParam "username"
    case username of
        Nothing -> writeBS "Capout"
        Just name -> do
            usernames <- query "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?" [(name)]
            case usernames of
                [] -> writeBS "Capout again"
                (h:_) -> writeBS $ theName (h :: Username)
```

This looks pretty much to what I would write in C or python so I was wondering what would be a better way for Haskell.

Thanks!

Comment: Monadic code modeling side effects often feels imperative, but there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You might want to take this over to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @overactor, that sounds nice, but my experience has been that very few Haskell programmers are answering questions on that site.

Comment: As @chi mentioned, monadic assignments (username <-) can feel imperative as monads are similar to OOP as they have a 'state', additionally case statements are also similar

Comment: @dfeuer "It won't get an answer there" doesn't imply "it's appropriate here".

Comment: chi and barbra: thanks folks, I just thought it was me and my imperative way of thinking. overactor and Daniel: thanks, I wasn't aware of codereview.SE. I will move it there! Edit: Not sure how i can move it however...